# Let $X$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\Bbb P)$. If $\Bbb E |X| \le 0$, show that $X=0$ almost surely.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\Bbb P)$. If $\Bbb E |X| \le 0$, show that $X=0$ almost surely.

**Definition.**
Let $X$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\Bbb P)$. The expectation of $X$ is defined to be
\begin{equation*}
\Bbb E X = \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) d\Bbb P(\omega),
\end{equation*}
if $X \ge 0$ almost surely.

**Definition.**
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\Bbb P)$ be a probability space. If a set $A \in \mathcal{F}$ satisfies $\Bbb P (A) = 1$, then the event $A$ occurs almost surely.

**attempt:**
By definition,
\begin{equation*}
\Bbb E |X| = \int_{\Omega} |X(\omega)| d\Bbb P(\omega) \le 0.
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, since $|X|\ge 0$, then $\Bbb E |X| \ge 0$.
Hence, $\Bbb E |X| = 0$. Then, $|X|=0$. Since $X \ge 0$, then $X=0$ almost surely.

I believe that this is not in the correct way, and the definition of "almost surely" doesn't occur, that is, $\Bbb P (X=0) =1$. Any ideas? How to approach it?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hint: If $A_n=\{|X|>\frac1n\}$ then $\{|X|>0\}=\bigcup_nA_n$. Notice that $0\leq P(|X|>0)\leq\sum_nP[A_n]\leq\sum_nnE[|X|;A_n]\leq\sum_nnE[|X|]\leq0$. Here, we are using Markov-Chebychev's inequality: $P[|X|>\lambda]\leq\frac1\lambda E[|X|;\{|X|>\lambda\}]\leq \frac1\lambda E[|X|]$

Comment: @OliverDiaz What is the meaning of $\Bbb E[|X|; A_n]$?

Comment: $E[|X|;A_n]=E[|X|\mathbb{1}_{A_n}]=\int_{A_n}|X|\,dP$

Comment: One last thing, $P[|X|>0]=0$ implies that $X=0$ $P$-almost surely. $X$ may still attain nonzero values, but that happens in a set of measure $0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672435/measure-theory-exercise-null-integral-implies-null-function

Comment: @blamethelag No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \Bbb P)$ and $\Bbb EX \le 0$. We want to show that $X=0$ almost surely, that is, $\Bbb P(A)=0$, where $A = \{\omega: X(\omega) \ne 0\}$. Define $A_n := \{\omega: |X(\omega)| \ge \frac1n\}$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.
Then, $A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Notice that $\{\omega:X(\omega) \ne 0 \} = \{\omega: |X(\omega)| \ne 0 \}$. Now, note that
\begin{align*}
0 \le \Bbb P(A) \le \Bbb P(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb P(A_n) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{A_n} d\Bbb P(\omega) \\
&\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{A_n} n|X(\omega)| d\Bbb P(\omega) \\
&\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \int_{\Omega} |X(\omega)| d\Bbb P(\omega) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\Bbb E|X| \\
&\le 0.
\end{align*}
Hence, $0 \le \Bbb P(A) \le 0$, which forces $\Bbb P(A) = 0$. Therefore, $X=0$ almost surely. $\qquad \qquad \Box$

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on your solution:

> By definition,
> \begin{equation*}
> \Bbb E |X| = \int_{\Omega} |X(\omega)| d\Bbb P(\omega) \le 0.
> \end{equation*}
> On the other hand, since $|X|\ge 0$, then $\Bbb E |X| \ge 0$.
> Hence, $\Bbb E |X| = 0$.

Good so far.

> Then, $|X|=0$.

I suspect you're supposed to say more here. Why would this follow from the above, and in what sense? It is true that what you've written so far implies that $|X| = 0$ *almost surely*, but I suspect from context that this is something you should *show* or *argue*.

> Since $X \ge 0$, then $X=0$ almost surely.

I don't think it's clear (or true) that $X \geq 0$, and I don't see why that would imply that $X = 0$ almost surely.

**HINT:** To repair this, consider a contrapositive approach. If $X \neq 0$ almost surely, then there exists some $A \subset \Omega$ with $\mathbb P(A) > 0$ so that $\omega \in A \implies |X(\omega)| > \epsilon$ for some positive $\epsilon$. (Why?) What would that imply?