# How to prove $\mathbb P(X\gt \mathbb E[X])=0\implies\mathbb P(X=\mathbb E[X])=1?$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

[This article](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2014.00577/full) contains the following (in the section "The Interface Theory of Perception", on page 4 of the .pdf):

> [...] we can think of a fitness function to be a function $f :W → [0,1],$ which
> assigns to each state $w$ of $W$ a fitness value $f(w).$ [...] If the true probabilities of states in the world are given by a probability measure $m$ on $W$, then one can define a new probability measure $mf$ on $W$, where for any event $A$ of $W$, $mf(A)$ is simply the integral of $f$ over $A$ with respect to $m$; $\ mf$ must of course be normalized so that $mf(W) = 1.$

Thus, $mf(W):= \int_W f\,dm=\mathbb E[f]$ (i.e. the expectation of $f$, assuming measurability), so the normalization requirement is just $\mathbb E[f]=1.$ Hence we have $f :W → [0,\mathbb E[f]],$ and therefore $m\{w:f(w)>\mathbb E[f]\}=0.$

**Question**: Isn't it the case that $$m\{w:f(w)>\mathbb E[f]\}=0\implies m\{w:f(w)=\mathbb E[f]\}=1?$$ In other words, haven't the authors unwittingly assumed a degenerate distribution?

These are probably elementary results that I've forgotten how to prove, but I seem to recall the following intuitive relations for any real r.v. $X$ with finite expectation: $$\mathbb P(X\gt \mathbb E[X])=0\iff \mathbb P(X\lt \mathbb E[X])=0\iff \mathbb P(X=\mathbb E[X])=1.$$

Comment: you assumption means $P[X\leq E[X]]=1$. That is, $Y=E[X]-Y\geq0$. On the other hand, $E[Y]=0$; hence $Y=0$ $P$-almost surely. This is because for any random variable $Y\geq0$,  $E[Y]=0$ implies that  $Y=0$ $P$-a.s. (that has been discussed many times in MSE, for example, [today](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4389709/121671) (see comments)

Comment: If $P[X \le EX] = 1$, then $0 \le EX -X$ ae. Since $E(EX-X) = 0$ this means $X=EX$ ae.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb P(X>\mathbb EX)=0$ does imply $\mathbb P(X=\mathbb EX)=1$, because $$\begin{align}\mathbb EX &= \int X = \int _{X\le \mathbb EX} X =\int_{\mathbb EX-\epsilon\le X\le \mathbb EX} X +\int_{X<\mathbb EX-\epsilon} X\\ &\le(\mathbb EX) \cdot \mathbb P(\mathbb EX-\epsilon\le X \le \mathbb EX) + (\mathbb EX-\epsilon)\mathbb P (X<\mathbb E X -\epsilon) \\ &=\mathbb EX -\epsilon\mathbb P(X<\mathbb E X-\epsilon)\end{align}$$

Hence $\epsilon\mathbb P(X<\mathbb E X-\epsilon)\le 0$ and $\mathbb P(X<\mathbb E X-\epsilon)=0$ for any $\epsilon>0$. And by continuity from below, $\mathbb P(X < \mathbb E X)=0$.

However, this is not what author means in the context. Let $(W, \mathcal B, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space, and $f:W\rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ be a non-negative function such that $0<\mathbb Ef=\int_W f<\infty$, then we may construct a new probability space $(W,\mathbb B, \mu)$, with $\mu(B)=\frac{\int_B f}{\int_W f}$. That is $\frac{f}{\int_W f}$ is the probability density of the new probability measure. In other words, probabilities are redistributed proportionally over $W$ according to $f$.

The author didn't claim that $\int_W f=1$ but one has to divide it to get a probability.